# Last cell keeps appearing on myUITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using the next code to add something specific to my last cell. I don't understand why when I'm scrolling my `UITableView` _buttonsView keeps appearing in other cells besides the last cell.
I thought about a quick solution and it is to add that specific view to a section but the current situation bugs me and I'd love to know how to fix it.

```
NSInteger rowsAmount = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]];
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCombinationCell"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[MyCombinationsCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"myCombinationCell"];
}    
if ([indexPath row] == rowsAmount - 1)
{
    _buttonsView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 317, 101);
    [cell addSubview:_buttonsView]; // _buttonsView is a few buttons inside a view
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to the use of reusable cells, it's a common issue. The problem is that it's using the last cell for reuse.

You can use a different identifier if the cell is different, or just "clean" the cell if it's not the last cell:

```
if ([indexPath row] == rowsAmount - 1)
{
    _buttonsView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 317, 101);
    [cell addSubview:_buttonsView];
}
else
{
 //Clean you cell
}
```

Comment: How can I clean the cell from that view? using `[ _buttonsView removeFromSuperView];` removes it from all cells. So is using `.alpha`

Comment: With clean I mean just remove what is not necessary, or re-create the normal cell. It depends on your implementation and what is in other cells, just understand that the cell is being reused, so you can for example remove all subviews on it

Comment: Like I wrote in my comment above, my problem is with the hiding part. If I hide that specific `UIView` in cell X it will also be hidden in the last cell.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the cell will be re-used. You need to have another condition removing(perhaps hiding the button if this is not the cell you want to append a button to.

E.g.

```
NSInteger rowsAmount = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]];
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCombinationCell"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[MyCombinationsCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"myCombinationCell"];
}    

if ([indexPath row] == rowsAmount - 1) {
    _buttonsView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 317, 101);
    [cell addSubview:_buttonsView];
} else {
    for(id view in cell.subviews){
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            NSLog(@"removing button");
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I clean the cell from that view? using `[ _buttonsView removeFromSuperView];` removes it from all cells. So is using `.alpha`

Comment: See my changed answer. NOTE: That is not a pretty solution but I think it will do what you want. I would however consider creating an custom UITableViewCell with a button and then hide/show it where it is required.

Comment: I still see the UIView with the buttons recreating in another cell